# Ravendb studio authentication

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Im running ravendb under shared hosting under IIS.
I have set up api key which enables me to call my my ravendb server from code. This all works fine.

The problem is i cant seem to figure out how to make this work with the Ravendb studio. As i see it the only option is to set <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/> the i need to change the server, eg add a database and back to <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="None"/> when im done.
Is there anyway to use the same oauth api key to access the studio as im using in my code?

If not, is there any work around you could surgest?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same Api Key also to get access for a specific database in the studio:

```
https://example.com/raven/studio.html#/home?api-key={api-kay}&database={database-name}
```

Comment: Cool, getting there. Is there a way i can get access to the [system] db this way. As far as i can read you cant do the with API-keys.

Comment: You need to grant permissions to the <system> database for that API key